# Bootstrap navbar, aligning right instead of left

Tags: html, css

i hope someone can help me with the following:
Why does this piece of HTML code for bootstrap navbar gives my Home to the right instead of left?

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

It works if i change `<div class="navbar-nav">` to `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">`
, but then the Home dissapears when scaling the browser window down, i dont want it collapsing. So how can i have it on the left, as simple as possible without collapsing or any other special effects? Here is an image of the left alignment:[Scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOhim.png)

Comment: Oh and ignore the Kali as a daily OS from the screenshot, its just my old laptop, I only use it for learning and practicing from my bed. I will install another OS soon enough.

Comment: Also maybe i should say that I'm learning from a Tutorial that uses bootstrap 4, so it's some different classes, and that doesen't help, i've read the documentation on bootstrap but cant find anything on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the class `mr-auto` to  `<div class="navbar-nav">` to make sure it is pushed to the left:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.2-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Or just *replace* `<div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">` with `<div class="mr-auto">`, see which suits you best:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.2-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <div class="mr-auto">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

add class `navbar-nav mr-auto` in ul

Comment: thank you sir, very much